# About Poisson's equation and its meaning

Tags: differentiation

So, by working out a physics equation, I ended up with Poisson's equation:
$$
\nabla^2A=G.
$$
Now the thing is, $A$ is not some sort of potential, but a physical quantity, energy in my case. If the Laplacian operator essentially gives you the curvature of the quantity $A$, so that if it is negative at a specific point for example, it's value there is greater than that of the surrounding points, then could we consider $G$ as a "source" term if it is negative, and a "sink" if it is positive? I know for the electric potential for example, a distribution of charges is a source for the electric *field*, which is the negative of the gradient of the potential. But what about when the quantity under the Laplacian is the more meaningful quantity?

Comment: Since you know that A is energy in your case, and that the same equation can apply to other quantities, what more can we tell you about it?

Comment: Well, am I supposing right or wrong in seeing $G$ as a source or sink for $A$, even if it is not a time evolution equation?